# Google Analytics event parameters only show in Event in last 30 min

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-console

I send some event information in parameters of my tracked events. But these parameters are only visible from the

`Events in last 30 min section`.

How do I see all the event parameters?

This is for both platforms iOS and Android

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to wait 24h to see data in the reports.

If you pass some parameters together with the events you must enable them in the interface defining custom dimensions and metrics (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en) to be able to see them in the platform, otherwise by connecting Analytics to BigQuery (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en) you will be able to see them there.

Comment: the data comes, what is sent in parameters is missing except in realtime view.

Comment: I am facing the same. Did you find out why? @ir2pid